# How to get the Joomla Update option to appear on the Components menu?

Tags: joomla-2.5, component, update

I've got a site running Joomla 2.5.14 that I want to update.

Apparently, [there should be an option](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Updating_Joomla_%28Update_Method%29) called "Joomla Update" on the Components menu that I can use to update the site, but it's not there.

I found [another page indicating how to get it to appear](https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_Update_Missing_in_from_Admin_Menu) when it's not there, but the SQL it suggests will not work because there doesn't exist a row in the menu table for the given filter `WHERE title = "com_joomlaupdate"`. As an alternative, it suggests using the Discover function to install it as a component.

Am I on the right track? What do I need to do to get Joomla Update to appear on the Components menu?

Comment: You may be able to browse to /administrator/index.php?option=com_joomlaupdate as a quick work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to update to 2.5.28 (the last J2.5 release)? If so then download https://mirror.myjoomla.io/Joomla_2.5.x_to_2.5.28-Stable-Patch_Package.zip and install it into your site just like an extension.
Always remember to back up and test your backup first though.
Once updated you should really then update to J3.4.7 as 2.5.x is end of life.

Answer (score 1):

One way that appears to allow the upgrade to be done without the menu option is to browse directly to URL **/administrator/index.php?option=com_joomlaupdate** within your site. If I understand correctly, this allows minor version updates, and for version 2.5.14 will allow updating to version 2.5.28 (at the current point in time).

I now also see that a major version update is available to me at the site URL **/administrator/index.php?option=com_cmsupdate**

This is on my Components menu as option "Akeeba CMS Update" and on my Control Panel as button "Joomla 3.5.1 is available".

Possibly these options require non-standard extension(s) though, as I appear to have a Component called "Cmsupdate" by author Nicholas K. Dionysopoulos and a Plugin called "Quick Icon - Akeeba CMS Update notification for Joomla! updates" by author "Nicholas K. Dionysopoulos / AkeebaBackup.com".

Comment: `/administrator/index.php?option=com_joomlaupdate` is the core Joomla update. `/administrator/index.php?option=com_cmsupdate` is a third party extension. Remember you'll still need to apply the hotfixes: https://docs.joomla.org/Security_hotfixes_for_Joomla_EOL_versions to keep the website secure until you can do the mini migration to Joomla 3.x.

Comment: The core Joomla Update component will also offer you an upgrade to Joomla 3.x once you change `Components -> Joomla Update -> Options` to "Short Term Support".

Comment: Note: Akeeba CMS Update is not supported since March 2016: https://www.akeebabackup.com/home/news/1662-software-availability-changes-march-2016.html